# Get next available number

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, common-table-expression

I have a `Bookmarks` table which contains a `smallint` column called `BookmarkNumber`.

Bookmarks are created and deleted.

When a new bookmark is created, e.g. with Id="oo", I want to create a new record with the next available `BookmarkNumber`. In the example below, this would be 4.

How does the query for this look like?

```
Id      | BookmarkNumber
-----------------
dd      | 1
aa      | 2
dd      | 3
tt      | 5
ff      | 27
uu      | 28
```

Comment: even when you make a trigger get a free number and insert it, you will notice, on heayvy load systems that you will get double numbers or deadlocks

Comment: The temptation to use the unused BookmarkNumbers from the middle of the range is real, but I strongly recommend you ignore it. Convert BookmarkNumber into an auto-incremented integer and be done with it.

Comment: Can't emphasise the above ^^^ too much. Don't complicate your life trying to fill in gaps... ask yourself whether it really makes a different to the end user - the answer is normally no.

Comment: You can bump smallint to int if you really feel stressed about running out of 32k numbers. EDIT: nice username!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`generate_series()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql) to create all numbers and find the minimum one not used:

```
insert into Bookmarks (Id, BookmarkNumber)
select 'xx', value
from (
  select min(value) as value
  from generate_series(1, 99)
  left join Bookmarks on BookmarkNumber = value
  where BookmarkNumber is null
) x
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/r2JhJRG-).

Chose the end range (I chose 99 here) to the smallest value definitely greater than the largest expected BookmarkNumber.

Because this is a single statement, and the database is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant, you will never get duplicates under heavy load.

Comment: This is a great solution for small numbers of rows. But when you start getting into larger datasets this is going to be a performance problem.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think there's any way around a performance problem given the problem statement.

Comment: @Bohemain - agreed. It would better if they would stop worrying about gaps in an identity. :D

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for :-)